# In SSIS can we route a Lookup Error Output to a Flat File Destination and simultaneously activate the OnError event

Tags: ssis, onerror

In an SSIS Data Flow Task (SSDT 2008 R2) I would like to route a Lookup Error Output to a Flat File Destination and simultaneously I would like to activate the OnError event handler to execute a Script Component to do other things (get the ErrorDescription). It seems that we can't have the both? Bachir

Answer (score 0):

What I do is use a "Multicast" to take the lookup error output and send it to the flat file and also a Script Component which gives you the same effect.

ed